# Cookies not working using WebClient on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies, windows-phone-8

My problem is when I use new webclient to send url to the WebService it asks me to login, and after searched about this issue I found that you need to save cookies but its not working with me.

And upon your request this is the full code

```
namespace PhoneApp8
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        public class OuterRootObject
        {
            public string d { get; set; }
        }

        public class Globals
        {
            public bool MultiSessionsAllowed { get; set; }
            public int CommCalcType { get; set; }
            public int PriceChangedTimer { get; set; }
            public int ValidLotsLocation { get; set; }
            public bool CustumizeTradeMsg { get; set; }
            public object FirstWhiteLabeledOffice { get; set; }
            public int DealerTreePriv { get; set; }
            public int ClientConnectTimer { get; set; }
            public int ClientTimeoutTimer { get; set; }
            public double DefaultLots { get; set; }
            public string WebSecurityID { get; set; }
            public int ServerGMT { get; set; }
        }

        public class VersionInfo
        {
            public int Rel { get; set; }
            public int Ver { get; set; }
            public int Patch { get; set; }
            public int ForceUpdate { get; set; }
            public int UpdateType { get; set; }
            public Globals Globals { get; set; }
        }

        public class SystemLockInfo
        {
            public int MinutesRemaining { get; set; }
            public int HoursRemaining { get; set; }
            public int DaysRemaining { get; set; }
            public int Maintanance { get; set; }
            public int WillBeLocked { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string sessionid { get; set; }
            public VersionInfo VersionInfo { get; set; }
            public SystemLockInfo SystemLockInfo { get; set; }
            public string FirstWhiteLabel { get; set; }
            public string WLID { get; set; }
            public bool CheckWhiteLabel { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastTickTime { get; set; }
            public int SelectedAccount { get; set; }
            public int Name { get; set; }
            public object ServicePath { get; set; }
            public string GWSessionID { get; set; }
            public string IP { get; set; }
            public string SessionDateStart { get; set; }
            public string CompanyName { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public string DemoClient { get; set; }
            public string FName { get; set; }
            public string SName { get; set; }
            public string TName { get; set; }
            public string LName { get; set; }
            public object Sms { get; set; }
            public string isReadOnly { get; set; }
            public string SchSms { get; set; }
            public string AlertSms { get; set; }
            public object Temp { get; set; }
            public string GMTOffset { get; set; }
            public string SvrGMT { get; set; }
            public object ClientType { get; set; }
            public string EnableNews { get; set; }
            public string PublicSlideNews { get; set; }
            public string PrivateSlideNews { get; set; }
            public int DealerTreePriv { get; set; }
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string baseuri = "http://IP in the comment/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/login?username=%22user15650%22&password=%22898k%22";
            CookieAwareWebClient wc = new CookieAwareWebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += ParseProducts_AsJson;
            Uri uri = new Uri(baseuri);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }

        private void ParseProducts_AsJson(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string raw = e.Result;
            string webResponse = e.Result;

            MessageBox.Show(webResponse as string);
            var outerRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterRootObject>(webResponse);
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(outerRoot.d);

            MessageBox.Show("hello " + root.Username + "    " + root.UserId + "    " + root.sessionid);
            var UserIdVal= Convert.ToInt16 (root.UserId);

            if (UserIdVal == -1 || UserIdVal == -207)
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
            else if (UserIdVal == -231)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must have at least one account");
            }

            else if (webResponse == null || webResponse == "" || UserIdVal < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while login.Please try later");
            }

            else if (UserIdVal > 0)
            {

                string baseuri1 = "http://IP in the comment/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/getallsymbols?AccountID=1122336675";
                CookieAwareWebClient wc1 = new CookieAwareWebClient();
                wc1.DownloadStringCompleted += ParseProducts_AsJson1;
                Uri uri1 = new Uri(baseuri1);
                wc1.DownloadStringAsync(uri1);
                MessageBox.Show("You have loged in");
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
            } 


        }

        private void ParseProducts_AsJson1(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string raw1 = e.Result;
            string webResponse1 = e.Result;
            MessageBox.Show(webResponse1 as string);
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
        {
            [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
            private CookieContainer cookie;

            public CookieContainer Cookie { get { return cookie; } }

            public CookieAwareWebClient()
            {
                cookie = new CookieContainer();
            }

            public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer givenContainer)
            {
                cookie = givenContainer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the error is in the cookie container, the last cookieaware i use (i have tried more than 10 cookie container codes)

Comment: Any help, i need to solve it :(

Comment: I have post here the full code and the ip is 74.54.46.178please help me to do this

Comment: Please help me, i have no solution to my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using

```
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

then i use the same cookieJar on the second request

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/getallsymbols?AccountID=1122336675")) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
{
    HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar))
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {




                //the code you need


            }
        }

    }

}, request);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code, what it does is it calls the first Url and get response if response is good, it copies the cookie to sessionCookie variable. and uses that in the second call

Declare sessioncookie some where in the same page

```
public static CookieContainer sessionCookie;
```

And Copy this in your button click

```
  public static async Task<string> SendRequestGetResponse()
    {
        try
        {
                   var postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://74.54.46.178/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/login?username=%22user15650%22&password=%22898k%22");

            postRequest.Method = "GET";
            if (sessionCookie == null)
            {
                postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            }
            else
            {
                postRequest.CookieContainer = sessionCookie;
            }

            HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await postRequest.GetResponseAsync();

            if (postResponse != null)
            {
                var postResponseStream = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
                var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(postResponseStream);

                string response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                if (sessionCookie == null)
                {
                    sessionCookie = postRequest.CookieContainer;
                }
            }

        var postRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://74.54.46.178/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/getallsymbols?AccountID=1122336675");              
            postRequest1.Method = "GET";
            if (sessionCookie == null)
            {
                postRequest1.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            }
            else
            {
                postRequest1.CookieContainer = sessionCookie;
            }

            HttpWebResponse postResponse1 = (HttpWebResponse)await postRequest1.GetResponseAsync();

            if (postResponse1 != null)
            {
                var postResponseStream1 = postResponse1.GetResponseStream();
                var postStreamReader1 = new StreamReader(postResponseStream1);

                string response1 = await postStreamReader1.ReadToEndAsync();

            }
     }
  }
```

Comment: its not working, i don`t know what is the problem, i think because the received cookies is httpOnly, please advice

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are setting the headers(like content type, Request type etc) for the login request and other requests. I have edit my answer and included  the portion where I am setting the Headers for the request.

Comment: Dear  Jagath  this is the full code that I use and the IP is 74.54.46.178, i know its not good code because I`m new in programming please help me to do this

Comment: I have edited my answer with my code because i was getting successful return.

Comment: Sorry dear its not working with my code, can you help me with my code i mean using the   class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient

Comment: Will give you answer in 1hr. I am trying that.

Comment: Sorry dear, i have tried your code, I tried to copy the cookie from first call to variable and used that in cookie in the second call but still I am not getting the result. Why can't you change your code to the code which worked for me? is there any specific reason?

Comment: honestly, i don't know how to use it if you have the full code please help me and i will use it()

Comment: Ok. I will edit my answer to give you the full code. please test this, This worked for me. You can copy this code in your button click ok

Comment: when i paste it give me errors:- windows phone 8 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. and 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponseAsync' and no extension method 'GetResponseAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference (Please advise)

Comment: the first error appeared on  await postRequest.GetResponseAsync();  is The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.

Comment: Ok, You cannot copy that to click method, you have to do it in some other method and make that method async. Then Try

Comment: the second error is 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponseAsync' and no extension method 'GetResponseAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: you got the response?

Comment: no because i cant run the code with these error as i told you i don't know how to use it

Comment: Sorry mate, I have given you the entire method that gave me result for your 2 urls. You have to try and resolve those errors yourself

Comment: Please help me, i have no solution to my problem, i have tried all possible solutions

Comment: Which the .net version you were having when you created theyour project?. I had 4.5 .net framework when I created the WP Project. I have 'using System.Net';and 'using System.Net.Http;'

Comment: I'm using .net 4.5 i do every thing with no luck, i need two button the first make login and the second make the second url with the same session id , please help

Comment: Have you got login response with any other method other than i have given here. if yes, did you try to copy the cookiecontainer like I have mentioned here and use that in your 2nd call

Comment: yes i have received login response and i get session id and i have tried to copy cookie container but with no luck, it seems i use wrong way , please advise me